# Problem with DISTINCT and Linq2SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have a table like this:

```
idinterpretation | iddictionary | idword | meaning
1                   1              1115     hello
2                   1              1115     hi
3                   1              1115     hi, bro
5                   1              1118     good bye
6                   1              1118     bye-bye
7                   2              1119     yes 
8                   2              1119     yeah
9                   2              1119     all rigth
```

And i try to get distinct rows (DISTINCT idword). So, at first i tried:

```
return dc.interpretations.Where(i => i.iddictionary == iddict).
    ToList<interpretation>().Distinct(new WordsInDictionaryDistinct()).
    OrderBy(w => w.word.word1).Skip(iSkip).Take(iTake);
```

But i have about 300.000 rows in my table and it is wrong solution.

Then, i tried:

```
    IEnumerable<interpretation> res = (from interp in dc.interpretations
                                      group interp by interp.idword into groupedres
                                      select new interpretation
                                      {
                                          idword = groupedres.Key,
                                          idinterpretation = groupedres.SingleOrDefault(i => i.idword == groupedres.Key).idinterpretation,
                                          interpretation1 = groupedres.SingleOrDefault(i => i.idword == groupedres.Key).interpretation1,
                                          iddictionary = groupedres.SingleOrDefault(i => i.idword == groupedres.Key).iddictionary
                                      }).Skip(iSkip).Take(iTake);
```

and i took error: `@foreach (interpretation interp in ViewBag.Interps)`  `System.NotSupportedException: Explicit construction of entity type 'vslovare.Models.interpretation' in query is not allowed.`

Is it really a way to take distinct rows and to have in finish rows like this:

```
idinterpretation | iddictionary | idword | meaning
1                   1              1115     hello
5                   1              1118     good bye
7                   2              1119     yes
```

?

---

dictionaries:

```
dictionary table

iddictionary | dictionary_name
```

words:

```
word table

idword | word_name
```

interpretations:

```
interpretation table

idinterpretation | iddictionary | idword | meaning
```

Comment: In the first code snippet, why do a ToList before the Distinct?  The ToList will cause all of the records not filtered by the Where to be pulled down from the database.

Comment: Because .Where(i => i.iddictionary == iddict).Distinct(new WordsInDictionaryDistinct()) give one more error: System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Distinct'.

Comment: I think that's because of new WordsInDictionaryDistinct() in the call to Distinct.  That is supposed to be an IEqualityComparer. Can you add your implementation of WordsInDictionaryDistinct to the question?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1208182.aspx/1

Comment: Also, where is this coming from? OrderBy(w => w.word.word1) Is "word" coming from a referenced table?

Comment: yes. Referenced table is (int, varchar) , (idword, word)

Comment: Can you edit your question a bit then? I'm not sure if you want data from that table in your final result or not because I don't see that table referenced in your second attempt.

Comment: I've answered but actually... now I've reread your changes I'm a bit lost - how did you end up with your "rows like this" - including rows with multiple values for iddictionary? Also really not sure about how  word1 ties in. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second attempt is almost there - you probably need to use a GroupBy clause to get this working within SQL.

Something like:

```
var query = from row in dc.interpretations
            where row.iddictionary == iddict
            group row by idword into grouped
            select grouped.FirstOrDefault();

return query.OrderBy(w => w.word.word1).Skip(iSkip).Take(iTake);
```

---

On why your query is taking too long - in general, if your query is slow it will be because the data you are searching and returning is really large - or because it is poorly indexed at the database level. To help find out, it is analysing or profiling your query - see this article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163749.aspx

Comment: So, how i should cast AnonymousType to IEnumerable<interpretation> or return AnonymousType?

Comment: I think the query in my answer should be returning an IQueryable<interpretation> - add ToList() to actually invoke the query into a IEnumerable<interpretation> (actually an IList<interpretation>

Comment: But, i cant understand, why is it still so long executing in time =\

Comment: what indexes do you have on your data?

Comment: Have added explanation in the answer